# Alternatives to say "顾名思义＂

Tags: idioms

I am reading a book to explain [factorial](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.1).

```
n! = n*(n-1)*(n-2)....3*2*1
```

Decompose word `factorial`阶乘, I am enlightened to see its meaning literally.

Since Factor is 乘数, So factorial should 阶乘.

How to describe such a situation?

"顾名思义"? 从字面上理解? 从拼写上理解?

I assume 顾明思议 a bit better but merely not grasp the idea thoroughly.

Are there some better phases?

Comment: I think this is just a way to construct English words. Curious to know what other people say.

Comment: I don't understand the question. :(

Comment: I think the question is motivated by how 阶乘 = "step multiplication" defines itself, and we're asking if there's a way to describe this property other than 顾名思义.  (Maybe 明 is a typo for 名?)

Comment: ty, I modified '顾名思义' @Becky李蓓

Comment: ＂拆字解字＂,  as an instance, decompose a Chinese character to parts to foretell things. @sylvia

Comment: I believe you mad a typo: `n! = n*(n-1)*(n-2)....3*2*2` -> `n! = n*(n-1)*(n-2)....3*2*1`

Answer (score 2):

What I can think of is: 逐字理解 or 按字面意思理解.

Comment: I got an idea "说文解字', so '拆字解字'  might be an option.

Comment: @Algebra those are not suitable because 拆字解字 is used to describe the action itself, not a way to understand.

Answer (score 1):

阶为逐级，乘为相乘，以阶乘冠factorial，可谓名实相合。

Answer (score 1):

「顾名思义」可以很好描述这种情况。由「阶乘」的名字可以推断其含义。「顾名思义」不等同于「从字面上理解」。「顾名思义」通常意味着这个名字取得好，很简洁，能准确的反应其意义。如果一个名字很长，例如中华人民共和国中央政府，一般不能使用「顾名思义」这个词，但是可以使用「逐字理解」。「顾名思义」通常还要求对名字的理解/推断是正确的，与它类似的一个词「望文生义」也表示从字面推断其含义，但是对应的推断是错误的。

「顾名思义」好像并没有什么特别好的同义词。